# matplotlib - savefig with text very slow

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-basemap

I just wondered about the performance of matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(). It's a simple map. With only the country-borders it takes around 1 sec. 
When i print a grid of only 21x19 values with text() on the map it needs 3 sec! Why is that so? Is there a workatound?

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import pickle
import numpy as np
import time

plt.clf()
m = pickle.load(open('a.pickle','rb'))
c = pickle.load(open('b.pickle','rb'))

x, y = m(lons, lats) # compute map proj coordinates

for i in range(322,343,1):       # lons
    for j in range(97,116,1):    # lats
        plt.text(x[j,i], y[j,i], int(round(data[j,i])),fontsize=7, color='k', ha='center', va='center')

print time.clock()-t1
plt.savefig('/var/www/img/test.png', bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches=0.05, dpi=100)
print time.clock()-t1
plt.close('all')
```

Comment: The very short answer is drawing text is slow and involves solving lots of (iirc) 4th order polynomials

Comment: is there something to avoid this?

Comment: hmmm. i doubt processing the figure through LaTeX would help much.

Comment: dont know, how to do this.

Comment: @tacaswell 4th order polynomials (`ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e==0`) have a well-defined analytical solution that can be precompiled and evaluated in milliseconds. According to the Abel-Ruffini theorem, only polyomials of order 5 and higher can't be solved analytically. If this is really the reason for it being slow, it means the developers of Matplotlib are really ignorant in basic analytical maths, which I really doubt. Are you sure this is the reason/bottleneck? I have the exact same problem with Matplotlib.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist A) You are being incredibly rude.  It is comments like this that gives us physicists a bad rep. Please grow up. B) Matplotlib uses freetype for text rendering C) there maybe memoization/caching opportunities that Matplotlib could use to speed this up, PRs are welcome.

Comment: @tacaswell Why am I being rude? Nothing I said is rude. You're being overly sensitive. Anyway, do you know whether such analytical solutions are being used, or whether they're solving such equations numerically? I can write C-extensions that solve polynomials up to 4th order very quickly, and I'm happy to help. I'm not familiar with font rendering, but I can provide fast solutions to the abstract problem of solving polynomials.